# WordPress: How to merge custom post type array?

Tags: arrays, wordpress, merge, custom-post-type

i try to setup a yearly (grouped by month) archive for *custom post types* in WordPress. But my code did not work as aspected. Maybe it is obiviously for someone who is more familar with WordPress and PHP but i can't get it work.

The code below is grouping by month **but** each post type by itself. Maybe i need to merge booth. But how?

```
<?php query_posts (array ('post_type' => array('images', 'articles')));?>

    <?php
        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

        // save month to a variable
        $month = the_date('M', '', '', FALSE);

        // If not used before print it 
        if ($month != $m_check) {
            echo "<h2>" . $month . "</h2>";
        }

        // save month to check variable
        $m_check = $month;
    ?>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br/>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query();?>
```

Regards, Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... after a cup of tea i got it with an other (probably better) approach.

#### Solution

```
<?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => array('images', 'articles'),
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => null,
        'post_parent' => null,
        );

    $posts = get_posts($args);

    if ($posts) {
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            setup_postdata($post);
            $month =  mysql2date('m', $post->post_date);

            if ($month != $check) {
                echo "<h2>" . $month . "</h2>";
            }

            // save month to check variable
            $check = $month;

            echo $post->post_title;
            echo '<br/>';
        }
    }

    ?>
```

#### Output

```
07
    Eagle creek
    Lorem Ispum dolor
    Vancouver Island
    Ottawa
    Vancouver
06
    Losabim oxygenium
```

Now it needs just a bit beautifying and i am done. By the way **@negatif**, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You will need this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/ to achieve what you want with custom posts.

Answer (score 0):

Easy and correct way to **merge our custom loop argument in default wordpress loop.**

```
    $argss = array(
            'paged' => $paged,
            'posts_per_page' => 9,
            'meta_query' => array(
                                'relation' => 'OR',
                                array (
                                    'key' => '_expiration-date',
                                    'value' => $tode,  // custom values
                                    'compare' => '>='
                                ),
                                array (
                                    'key' => '_expiration-date',
                                    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                                ),
                            ),
        );


        global $wp_query;

        // Merge custom query with $wp_query
        $merged_args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, $argss );

        // Query posts using the modified arguments
        query_posts( $merged_args );

        if ( have_posts() ) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        ..
         else : ?>
        <p><?php _e('Apologies, but no entries were found.', 'tb'); ?></p>
    <?php endif;

    //wp_reset_query();

    ?>
```